# Replace foreign key with value from linked table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following tables.

```
Table-A

id int(11)
table_b_id int(11)// foreign key to table_b
name varchar

Table-B

id int(11)
name varchar
```

Now I redesigned the db schema so that the `table_b_id` field type is changed to`varchar`. How can I replace the `table_b_id`'s value to corresponding `name` value on `Table-B` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET table_b_id =(
       SELECT name FROM TableB
       WHERE id = TableA.table_b_id
    )
```